# Android: Ошибка в парсинге текста

Tags: android, java, строки

Есть текст, что-то вроде такого **"ля-ля-ля%sep%ы-ы-ы-ы"** и так до 50 разделений **%sep%** между текстом. Цель - каждую подстроку в строке поместить в массив, удалив **%sep%**.

Вот наработка:

```
Utils.separator2 = "%sep%";
     for(int j = 0; j < 50;j++)
            {
                if(texter.indexOf(Utils.separator2) > 0)
                {
                    newtext = texter.substring(0, texter.indexOf(Utils.separator2));
                    myList[j] = newtext;
                    if(texter.indexOf(Utils.separator2) + 5 < texter.length())
                    {
                        texter = texter.substring(texter.indexOf(Utils.separator2) + 5,texter.length());
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                    Log.i("lab",texter);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
Ошибка:

    10-24 20:55:30.166    5425-5425/com.how E/lab﹕ [ 10-24 20:55:30.167  5425:0x1531 D/ActivityThread ]
    ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{417611d0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@416680f0 {com.how/com.how.BuyListView}}
10-24 20:55:30.196    5425-5425/com.how E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гм. Возможно я что-то не понял, но чем вас не устраивает обычный

```
str.split("%sep%");
```

?

Comment: @Ques не ищет легких путей!!!